# How can be a docker container restarted periodically?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a container with a listener to azure servicebus queue, which goes idle after 20 hours or so and never activates again. When I restart the container, it is all good for next 20 hours. But this mustn't be done manually.

How can I instruct the container (preferably using its docker-compose.yml file?) to restart every lets say 10 hours?

Comment: Tried [this](https://gist.github.com/kizzx2/782b500a81ce46b889903b1f80353f21/revisions)?

Comment: Nice one, seems to execute, but results in `/bin/sh: 1: docker: not found` but I guess that is to do with the fact that bash from the container has no access to the docker process running on the host machine?

Comment: How would you do this if the listener were running directly on your host system, without Docker?

Comment: I don't understand